# How to enable LSAN detect memory leaks at runtime, and not wait until the end of the process

Tags: memory-leaks, clang, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

I have an ASAN instrumented 'deamon' process that always runs in my system. I see the memory leaks are reported only when the process exits. Is there anyway that i can ask LSAN to dump the leak reports without having to kill the process ? Is there any signal that i can send to process , so that it will detect and dump the leaks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [__lsan_do_leak_check](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libsanitizer/include/sanitizer/lsan_interface.h):

```
  // Check for leaks now. This function behaves identically to the default
  // end-of-process leak check. In particular, it will terminate the process if
  // leaks are found and the exitcode runtime flag is non-zero.
  // Subsequent calls to this function will have no effect and end-of-process
  // leak check will not run. Effectively, end-of-process leak check is moved to
  // the time of first invocation of this function.
  // By calling this function early during process shutdown, you can instruct
  // LSan to ignore shutdown-only leaks which happen later on.
```